# ajax post returns laravel error 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I added the csrf token and it still returns that error. Unfortunately everywhere I search is just telling me to add that to my view but if I already have that what am I supposed to do from here?

```
<meta name="_token" content="{!! csrf_token() !!}" />

...

$('#like_unlike').on("submit", function( event ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
            $.ajax({
                url: '{{ route('art.like') }}',
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    _token : $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
                    data:$('#like_unlike').serialize()
                }, // Remember that you need to have your csrf token included
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function( _response ){
                    console.log(_response)
                },
                error: function( _response ){
                    console.log('failure')
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: First open the network tab in Google chrome and then check in header that if you're actually sending the Token in headers, If so then clear your route cache and debug it

Comment: I was sending the token the problem lied elsewhere

Comment: Check encoding of your files and tried with UTF 8 w/o BOM. Also check permission of path to your files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research I found that if you go into `/storage/logs` and find the date of your log and scroll all the down to the latest stacktrace, you can usually deduce the error. In my case I was calling upon a key that didn't exist in my json object. This is most likely the cause of error in a lot of cases, but again go check `/storage/logs` and you can find what the error causing the Internal Server Error is.